# How could the admin reset the password of a user on domains.live.com

Tags: outlook.com

I'm managing a website for someone and I hosted the emails on [domains.live.com](http://domains.live.com) (Outlook free domain email hosting).

A user (user@example.com) forgot his password, and his security question, so if he wants to reset his password, he has to request that from the Outlook team.

I know the admin password and I wonder if I can login as an admin and somehow reset his password. Is this possible?

**Edit**

I deleted the account and recreated it, since no one answered, but I'm still looking for solutions, in case I encounter this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently having the same issue. Apparently, you have to contact Microsoft (for instance through their forums) and ask them to enable this functionality for you.

I haven't figured out yet how to post there, but looking at other posts, that should do it.

Comment: I was able to post a question there on January 22nd, but I haven't received an answer yet. I assume you're quickest if you just go to the accounts support and chat with or call them.